# Why is my NSTableView data source illegal?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

For some reason, I'm getting the following error:

*** Illegal NSTableView data source ().  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

Here's my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate> {

    NSMutableArray *userNotifications;
}

@property NSMutableArray *userNotifications;

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize userNotifications;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSUserNotification *userNotification = notification.userInfo[NSApplicationLaunchUserNotificationKey];

    userNotifications = [NSMutableArray new];

    if(userNotification) {
        [self userActivatedNotification:userNotification];
    } else {
        for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++) {

            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Title %d", i];
            NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Message %d", i];

            NSArray *notificationObj = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:title, message, nil];
//          NSLog(@"Array: %@", notificationObj);
            [userNotifications addObject:notificationObj];
//          NSLog(@"Notifications: %@", userNotifications);
            [self deliverNotificationWithTitle:title message:message];
        }
    }

}

- (void)deliverNotificationWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                            message:(NSString *)message
{

    NSUserNotificationCenter *center = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];
    NSUserNotification *userNotification = nil;

    userNotification = [NSUserNotification new];
    userNotification.title = title;
    userNotification.informativeText = message;

    center.delegate = self;
    [center scheduleNotification:userNotification];

}


- (void)userActivatedNotification:(NSUserNotification *)userNotification
{
//  [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotification:userNotification];

    printf("* User activated notification:");
//  NSLog(@"Title: %@", userNotification.title);just do it in
//  NSLog(@"Message: %@", userNotification.informativeText);
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/"]];
}

- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center
     shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)userNotitification
{
    printf("* Notification presented.");
    return YES;
}


- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [userNotifications count];
}
- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return [userNotifications objectAtIndex:row];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why all those semicolons before the left braces of your function bodies?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but do you really want to use [userNotifications addObject:notificationObj] which will add the notificationObj array as one element in userNotifications, or do you want to use addObjectsFromArray: which will add the 2 objects individually?

Comment: @HO2CO3: I think it was in the example I copied and pasted from.

Comment: @rdelmar One element - title and message go together. I'm just prototyping this out now, but eventually that Notification is going to have it's own class/CoreData stuff.

Comment: sluther - that's a hint that they shouldn't be there.  What happens when you delete them?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Yeah, I gathered that. No change when they are removed that I can tell, and I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and I don't get any errors. I get 10 new notifications popping up, but nothing in my table view.  BTW, did you set your app delegate to be the data source of your table view?

Comment: @rdelmar I actually hadn't done that. Now that I've fixed it, no more error - but nothing in the table view still (which is actually expected at this point!). I'm having another issue now with a button I've created - I connected it directly to an IBAction in my AppDelegate.h file, but I get the following error now:

Could not connect the action refresh: to target of class AppDelegate

Comment: I had to add an outlet to the table view and call reload data at the end of the applicationWillFinishMethod (I think the table view is loaded before the other things you do in that method, so that's why nothing shows up). I still get nothing but () in the table view though, because you're returning an array rather than a string in your  data source method

Comment: @rdelmar Yeah, I'm aware - I'm planning on pulling the data out of that array and assembling them into the table contents. Any ideas on the IBAction issue I'm seeing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set my App Delegate as the data source for the Table view. Once I did that, the errors disappeared.